# PHP read input from form and save to txt

Tags: php

I am trying to make a form which saves the user's inputs into a txt file using PHP. My code doesn't seem to work. Can someone help me?

index.php

```
<center>
    <div class="profile">
        <div class="infocontainer">
        <form action="processing.php" method="POST">

        <p class="urlr">
        <center>URL 1:</center>
        <input type="url" name="field1">
        <center>URL 2:</center>
        <input type="url" name="field2">
        <center>URL 3:</center>
        <input type="url" name="field3">
        <center>URL 4:</center>
        <input type="url" name="field4">
        <center>URL 5:</center>
        <input type="url" name="field5">
        </p>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save Data">
        </form>
        </div>
  </div>
</center>
```

processing.php

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['field1']) && isset($_POST['field2']) && isset($_POST['field3']) && isset($_POST['field4']) && isset($_POST['field5'])) {
    $data = $_POST['field1'] . '-' . $_POST['field2'] . '-' .  $_POST['field3'] . '-' .  $_POST['field4'] . '-' .  $_POST['field5'] ."\n";
    $ret = file_put_contents('/campaign/mydata.txt', $data, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
    if($ret === false) {
        die('There was an error writing this file');
    }
    else {
        echo "$ret bytes written to file";
    }
}
else {
   die('no post data to process');
}
?>
```

All i get is "There was an error writing this file"

Comment: Go to your server logs in /var/log/apache2/error.log. You can see what caused this. Most likely this is a permission error, where the web server was unable to access the file.

Comment: there is nothing wrong with the code?

Comment: If file_put_contents returned false, it means that is where the error is. http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php

Comment: Also, try changing ```'/campaign/mydata.txt'``` to ```'./campaign/mydata.txt'```. The  dot at the beginning means "current directory". Thanks to @rioyotto(answer below) for pointing this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this line of code

`$ret = file_put_contents('/campaign/mydata.txt', $data, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);`

with

`$ret = file_put_contents('campaign/mydata.txt', $data, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);`

`/` in the beginning of file directory adds another slash in file link and make the file link invalid.

Answer (score 1):

i test your scripts it's working fine.

must be because the folder (have / in it)
$ret = file_put_contents('/campaign/mydata.txt', $data, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);

change it to this : 
$ret = file_put_contents('campaign/mydata.txt', $data, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);

check the folder campaign.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the folder **campaign** resides same level at index.php and processing.php, The script is writing the data properly.

i have changed one line code here:

```
$ret = file_put_contents('campaign/mydata.txt', $data, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```

I checked the script in local, it is working fine.

Thanks
Amit